# Error merging powerpoint slides containing videos using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm using the Open XML SDK to combine a number of slides from various powerpoint presentations based on a users input. I have a web interface that allows users to select the slides they want then I'm using the SDK to create the presentation. I'm starting with a blank powerpoint and adding slides from existing presentations to it.

I'm using the code straight from the Microsoft MSDN to do this:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee361883(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee361883%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

This works fine for most slides, the problem occurs when I try to add/merge a slide with a video on it. When the line

```
destSp = destPresPart.AddPart<SlidePart>(sp, relId);
```

hits a slide with a video on I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.AddSubPartFromOtherPackage(OpenXmlPart part, IDictionary`2 partDictionary, IDictionary`2 dataPartsDictionary, Boolean keepIdAndUri, String rId)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.AddSubPartFromOtherPackage(OpenXmlPart part, Boolean keepIdAndUri, String rId)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.AddSubPart(OpenXmlPart part, String rId)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.AddPartFrom(OpenXmlPart subPart, String rId)
>      at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.AddPart[T](T part, String id)
>      at Program.MergeSlides(String presentationFolder, String sourcePresentation, String destPresentation) in c:\Projects\powerpoint_test\powerpoint_test\Program.cs:line 117

Comment: I've found a workaround for this by using the PresentationBuilder library. There's a video explaining how to use it (and why it is required) here: [link](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2013/01/14/quick-introduction-to-presentationbuilder.aspx).

Comment: You can download the library/source for this solution [here](http://powertools.codeplex.com/releases/view/74771)

Comment: Seems like video is moved. Can you share the solution?